# Multiple dynamic HTTP endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to run multiple HTTP endpoints which should be creates based on list of paths.

Currently I'm able to create one endpoint:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "requestChannel")
public interface Gateway {
    String sendReceive(String in);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("requestChannel").transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer())
            .handle(new MyHandle())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpGate() {
    HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(true);
    RequestMapping mapping = new RequestMapping();
    mapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
    mapping.setPathPatterns("/path");
    gateway.setRequestMapping(mapping);
    gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
    gateway.setRequestPayloadType(byte[].class);
    return gateway;
}
```

but I want to do somthing like this:

```
@Autowired
List<String> paths;

@PostConstruct
public void createEndpoints() {
    for (String path : paths) {
        //code for dynamic endpoint creation
    }
}

private class MyHandle extends AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler {

    @Override
    protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage) {
        return this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload("Your message: " + requestMessage.getPayload());
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since Java DSL 1.2 there is a `IntegrationFlowContext`exactly for such a use-case to register `IntegrationFlow` and dependent beans dynamically.

https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available

The GA release today.

You should just follow with the samples in those blog post and pay attention to the `org.springframework.integration.dsl.http.Http` factory.

But, indeed, do that as early as possible. The `@PostConstruct` is good phase for this use-case.
When it will be later, the `HandlerMapping` won't be able to detect an new mapping. Just because it does the scan in its `afterPropertiesSet()`.